# Why is $\exp(n/2 * (\log 2)^2) \approx 1.27^n$

Tags: exponentiation, approximation

I saw this approximation made in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473496/infinite-coin-toss-probability by the accepted answer.

What inspired this approximation?

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $\ln x^a = a \ln x$ and $x^a = e^{a \ln x}.$

So, we can rewrite this expression as $e^{n \ln\left(2^{\frac{\ln 2}{2}}\right)} = \left(2^{\frac{\ln 2}{2}}\right)^n \approx 1.27^n.$

Comment: Ah. I actually got rid of the log earlier and got that the expression is about $\exp(0.24n)$. Is there any way to go from this form to $1.27^n$?

Comment: @David $e^{0.24n} = (e^{0.24})^n \approx 1.27^n$.

Comment: @RaviFernando Oh man I definitely brain farted here.

Comment: I think I'm not seeing where the $e^{n \ln (2^{\ln(2) / 2})}$ came from. Did you skip a step?

Comment: @David I guess kind of? I started with $e^{n \ln (2) \cdot \frac{\ln (2)}{2}}$ and then used the first rule